# How to dynamically generate my form validate content and make it works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a checkbox in my code for choose if yes or no I want to put an errorClass in my form validate. So my form validate content is generated automatically but it works the first time only.

My HTML :

```
<form id="myForm">
   <label>Email <input type="text" name="email" /><label>
   <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

<label>Set errorClass <input type="checkbox" name="errorClass" /></label>
```

My jQuery :

```
$('input[name="errorClass"]').change(function() {
   var class = ($('input[name="errorClass"]').checked) ? "has-error" : "";

   $("#myForm").validate({
      rules: { email: 'required' },
      errorClass: class
   });
});
```

How to make it works every time I check or uncheck my checkbox ?

Answer (score 0):

Variable name '*class*' may throw an error as it is a reserved word. Also from inside the change function you may reference the object with '*this*' keyword.
Try the following:

```
$('input[name="errorClass"]').change(function() {
  if(this.checked){
    var cls = "has-error";
    $("#myForm").validate({
      rules: { email: 'required' },
      errorClass: class
    });
  } else {
    var validator = $( "#myForm" ).validate();
    validator.resetForm();
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.